# How to get IR1 and IR2 camera images from Intel RealSense D415 using OpenCV-Python?

Tags: python, opencv, realsense

I am using D415 Intel Realsense Stereo Camera, I want to access the left camera and right camera of D415 stereo camera, I have tried the below code

```
pipeline=rs.pipeline()

config = rs.config()
config.enable_stream(rs.stream.infrared, 1, 1280, 720, rs.format.y8, 30)
config.enable_stream(rs.stream.infrared, 2, 1280, 720, rs.format.y8, 30)

pipeline.start(config)
```

while I am executing the line "pipeline.start(config)", I am getting the following error!!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ir1_ir2.py", line 10, in <module>
        pipeline.start(config)
RuntimeError: Couldn't resolve requests
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this error!!

Answer (score 0):

For my question, I found an answer.
  we have to enable the *custom* view in realsense-viewer, then only we can able to get the frames from our code.

```
config.enable_stream(rs.stream.infrared, 1, 480, 270, rs.format.y8, 30)
config.enable_stream(rs.stream.infrared, 2, 480, 270, rs.format.y8, 30)
```

we have to add this configeration to our config.